# Carrierwave default Image not showing in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, carrierwave

Hi I am working with carrierwave and I am using default Image as below.

```
def default_url
 ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path([version_name, "image.png"].compact.join('_'))
end
```

It is working fine in development but image not loading in production in heroku.

The Image URL is showing as below both in production and development.

```
/assets/tiny_thumb_image.png
```

but I have checked

```
puts helper.asset_path("small_thumb_image.png")
```

in heroku console. the output is something like below with fingerprints included in the filename.

> /assets/tiny_thumb_image-2372152cb18fd9aac1004f781047ee6a.png

I have also included

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Answer (score -1):

Try uploading your default image into the

```
assets/images
```

path, that is how it works with me